# Should I test if an element exist before doing anything to it?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I had the following HTML and Javascript.  Here, there is only 1 div on the page, but at any given time, there could be a total of 2 divs (dynamically inserted).

In jQuery, should you first test to see if an element exists before doing anything to it, especially if you know there's a chance it might not be present?

Should I test it with `if (('#div2).length > 0)`?

Or should I just let jQuery figure it out?  I know if doesn't exist, jQuery is smart enough to know the element isn't there, so it won't do anything to it nor would it throw an error.  But is it better to first test to see if it exist?  Best practice maybe or is there a performance difference?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#div1').text('Hello World!');

/*
  Should I first test and see if this div exists?
  With if (('#div2').length > 0)
  Or leave it as is and let jQuery handle it
*/
$('#div2').text('Should I have first tested to see if this div existed?');
```

Comment: What does testing for it buy you? You could throw an exception, I suppose .. but most jQuery methods will "work fine" (as in, not do anything) on empty element sequences. If you're not going to do anything different if it doesn't exist, then don't bother to check.

Comment: It all depends on the application business logic, not on best practices. If you don't care if nothing happens if element doesn't exist - then you don't care.

Comment: There is no need to test if an element exists, unless you need to explicitly check if it exists for someething where that would be important. Just randomly checking every element for existance in the DOM is unneccessary and clutters up code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object returned by jQuery's factory function is array-like. The selected DOM elements will be set to numeric indices (`{0: elem1, 1:elem2, etc}`). The length property will be set to the number of matched elements.

jQuery's methods are all designed to iterate over the collection of elements to perform an action. This essentially means that `obj.test('foo')` is equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    obj[i].textContent = 'foo';
}
```

If there are no elements in the collection, the methods don't perform any action, because the iterator never iterates.

So, tl;dr, there's rarely ever a reason to check if the selection contains elements before performing actions on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you probably should not have code that executes on an element that is not there. That being said, I can't imagine any real problems that would arise from performing an operation on a selector with no matched elements. So there should not be a need to test it.

jQuery loops over all matched elements to perform the operation on, so if it matches no elements, it will just loop over nothing. Aside from an very very minor *potential* performance increase, I do not see what you would gain.

***"Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil."*** -Donald Knuth